# Extract all values from a range using regexp in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Example:

```
'R1-R5,C1-C2,W11-W14'
```

will become:

```
'R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,C1,C2,W11,W12,W13,W14'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question. Among the others, consider that questions like "how to do this" are not usually welcome, if not showing any effort. Some hints: post what you tried so far, your attempts and the result of your searching, event better formatting the data and clarifying you table structure ( is your starting string a single value? is it the result of a concatenation? ...)

Comment: Also, why is R5 duplicated in your needed result?

Comment: Sorry it's a mistake R5 should NOT be duplicated. The example is stored in a column of an oracle table as varchar2(500)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your elements are always in the form `XN-XM` where `X` is a single character, `N` and `M` are integer positive numbers and `N<M`, you may need the following:

```
with yourString(s) as ( select 'R1-R5,C1-C2,W11-W14' from dual) 
select listagg( substr(s, 0, 1) || to_char( level -1 + to_number( substr(s, 2, instr(s, '-') -2 ))), ',') 
              within group ( order by l, level)
from (
        SELECT regexp_substr(s, '[^,]+', 1, level) s, level as l
          FROM yourString
        CONNECT BY instr(s, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
     )  
connect by level -1 + to_number( substr(s, 2, instr(s, '-') -2 )) <= to_number( substr(s, instr(s, '-') +2))
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
       and prior l = l
order by 1
```

Here the inner `CONNECT BY` is used to split your string into single intervals (`R1-R5` for example ) and the outer one is made to "duplicate" the row according to the range.

The `listagg` simply aggregates the resulting strings, according to the order given by the position in the original string and the value of the single item within the range.

Comment: If the answer ir right for you, please accept it. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something on what to do when someone answers